# Application won't hide on startup

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having trouble with the application *Brow* that won't hide on login, even when the option is selected in Preference System.

System's 10.8.4, and [here's the application](http://d.pr/i/30Qg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something probably activates *Brow* after hiding it. You can [write an AppleScript/Automator-action](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20056562-263.html) to re-hide it.

Comment: Strangely, that Applescript worked with every app, except Brow…
I managed to mask it when closing the window `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "w" using command down`